# How to read and output the XML within an SPFile?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sharepoint-2010

I have this line of code that retrieves and XML file and saves it to an SPFile

```
SPFile XMLFile = SPContext.Current.Web.GetFile("C:\\Users\\maleem\\Documents\\XMLTest.xml");
```

I want to get the XML/Text within it and output it to a literal, I tried

```
StreamReader  reader = new StreamReader(XMLFile.OpenBinaryStream());
```

And a few variants but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the **OpenBinary** method of **SPFile** the return is a byte array you can then convert it into a string.

Depending on the encoding you can try this:

For default encoding:

```
string str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(XMLFile.OpenBinary());
```

For UTF8:

```
string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(XMLFile.OpenBinary());
```